# How can I get the Google Search menu back to the left side and see "total results" stats?

Tags: firefox, google-search

I'm using Firefox. One week ago Google changed its design, moving the menu to the top:

[image]

That's fine with me, but I often need the "total results" stats, so I googled hard to change it back. No results.

Today I changed my browser and it displayed the good old design. Menu on the left, total results on its place.

I changed `google.com` to other languange (not `.com`) in FIrefox and it shows the old design again. So, only `google.com` has problems, not all Google versions.  I also started Firefox in safe mode, nothing changed. So, it is not an add-on causing the problem.

What can it be? How can I move menu back to the left and see result stats?

Comment: I used the exact same search within IE8 and the menu was on the left.  **It sounds like Google might have changed its layout for just Firefox.**

Comment: I also use Firefox, and I cannot reproduce this result...

Comment: Try clearing your cache and see if that makes it go away

Comment: @m4573r - What version of firefox are you on? And what about you, Qiao?

Comment: @SaintWacko `15.0.1`. I have this problem neither on `.com` nor on any language specific version.

Comment: @m4573r - I'm curious to see if you two have the same version. I'm on Chrome, and my menu is on the left still. And I just checked the desktop, which is running FF15.0, and it has it on the left.

Comment: @slhck - I would make an argument it does make a difference considering I got search results when I spelled the word correctly that explained the problem. This was actually I changed Google pushed awhile ago.  The reason I don't see it is because its not supported by IE8.

Comment: @SaintWacko, 15.0.1 also

Comment: @Qiao - Hm, well, good thing the cache trick worked then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please clear the firefox cache, it might have been corrupted.

See here for [instructions](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, Google is testing a new layout. This experimental layout takes the search options and moves them above the search results. Google already tried something very similar [back in June](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-user-interface-test-15330.html). Since this is the way the search options are displayed on a tablet Google may well be trying to unify the looks.